# i cant return a exist view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

im new in laravel i try a create a trash a view but i can't retrun the trash page and i retrun
show page so how can i fix it
the error : **View [products.show] not found.** and i didnt use this file

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


   Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

**productController.php**

```
public function trash()
   {
        return view('products.trash');
        
    }
```

**trash.blade.php**

```
<h1>this is a trash page</h1>
```

Comment: is your file here: resources/views/products/trash.blade.php

Comment: Second:  resource routs can only have methods `index,create,store,show,edit,update,destroy` in their controllers. (You can overwrite them) but if you are just starting use this syntax `Route::get('products',[ProductController::class,'trash']);`   and be sure to add the `use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;` to the top of your routes.php file

Answer (score 3):

Only 7 standard functions can be used by Route::resource. You can't name your functions randomly. You shhould use index or show function to display something.

In the terminal, type php artisan route:list and see the product routes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to use the Controller's __invoke function, you need to add the function name to the call with @ notation:

```
Route::get('products', 'ProductController@trash');
```

Along with this, the Resource portion means you are explicitly telling Laravel this is a resource, and it can only use certain URIs. More here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

So to do the *resource* route, you'll want to instead change your function name, something like:

```
   public function destroy()
   {
        return view('products.destroy');
        
   }
```

Comment: Yeah I submitted early. Already fixed.

Comment: i use it before but its doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Route:: resource than you must have its defined functions index , create , store , edit , update , destroy and show..

You can see more details regarding this here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: i defined them but i dont copied here

Comment: the problem when i try to create a new page he redirect me to show page all the time

Comment: Try to check the route of trash function then ! There maybe some mistake !

Comment: i use name to fix it thanks for ur help !

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Just rename the function `trash` to `index` in the controller.

Or

Option 2: Specify to call function trash in `web.php` (Route File)

```
Route::get('products', [ProductController::class, 'trash']);
```